# Start exe even with missing dependency dlls?

Tags: .net, configuration, compiler-construction, attributes, assemblies

In Dotnet2.0 and later a program refuses to start if one of its dependent (static referenced) dlls are missing.

With Dotnet1.1 and 1.0 the program started but crashed later when trying to use functionality of the missing assembly.

I wonder if there is something like a

- compiler switch ,
- configuration option or
- a dotnet [attribute]

to allow me to start the app when 
certain dlls are missing.

Is it possible without moidfying the sourcecode (execpt by applying some Attriutes)?

I don't want to manualy load assemblies by programcode or use IOC-Framworks.

Update: With "static referenced dlls" i mean the opposite of dynamicly loading a dll in my own programcode using reflection and Assembly.Loadxxxx().

Update 2010-12-25 I was thinking to complicated. Thanks simple solution from @erinus:

i just have to put try catch around and it worked:

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using log4net; // log4net.dll might be missing

    namespace ConsoleAppWithMissingDll
    {
        class Program
        {
            static bool dllIsInstalled = true;
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello missing dll");

                try
                {
                    OutputViaLog4Net("hello log4net");
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    dllIsInstalled = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Log4net-dll not found");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Program continued");
    #if DEBUG
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
    #endif
            }

            private static void OutputViaLog4Net(string message)
            {

                ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger");

                logger.Debug(message);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you ever want an application to start if dependencies are missing? I would much rather it not start than crash after I has done some work.

Comment: @Oded i had a dotnet-cf-1.1 library that ran unmodified on ppc2003 and on a webservice server. Altough it has a few methods that reference to dotnet-cf-only-api-s i was able to use most of it in the webservicet-server.

Comment: @Oded Sometimes it can be useful to allow the user to run the program in a degraded fashion. For example in the days before DirectX 9 was installed on all Windows machines we would use it in our app if it was available and otherwise report its absence. That was much better for our users of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unmanaged code. Call Windows API: LoadLibrary in try{...}catch{...} block. If dll is missing, handle exception and keep the process run.

Comment: Call Windows API is not necessary. Try catch is enough. Thanks for inspiration. Added testprogram to quiestion.

Comment: ^^ You're right! I usually call LoadLibrary because of my dlls made by VC6. If your dll made by .NET, just try{...}catch{...}. Thanks for note.

Answer (score 3):

A "statically referenced dll" is an oxymoron, the d in dll means "dynamic".  There are implicitly referenced dlls but only unmanaged code uses those.  You cannot start a program with such a DLL missing, the dll is loaded before the program's entrypoint starts executing.

.NET loads dlls on demand, triggered by the JIT compiler.  As soon as it compiles a method of a type that's stored in that DLL will the DLL be loaded.  Shipping code with such a DLL missing is technically possible, you have to be careful to write your code so that a type from such a DLL is never used.  This is the desktop version behavior, not quite sure if the CF version works the same way.

Comment: I think you are being a little harsh here. Such DLL references can easily be viewed as having static qualities. These references in the DLL imports table are not *as dynamic* as DLLs loaded up programmatically with GetProcAddress.

Comment: The technical background you gave (and i agree with) is marked as an answer but i cannot figure out how to "Start exe even with missing dependency dlls" execept that "Shipping code with such a DLL missing is technically possible".

Comment: I'm not close enough to see, but the stack trace of the exception ought to provide some clues as to how the type from the missing assembly got to be referenced.  Make sure to look at the inner exception.